# JSTL Persistence Query from single table

Tags: java, jstl

I have a database that is set up as follows:

```
ID | Environment | Name | Value
______________________________
1  | test        | prop | value
2  | ex          | prop | value2
```

In my java class I have the query:

```
List<Test> test = em.createQuery(
    "select p from DB p where p.environment=:env or p.environment=:env2")
```

and set the `:env` and `:env2` variables via a `getParameter`

In the jsp file I have:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Value2</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${test}" var="test">
        <tr>
            <td><b>${test.name}</b></td>
            <td>${test.value}</td>
            <td>???????</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

My question is in the row with the question marks, how do I combine the results of the query so that each prop 'name' is a row, and the 2 values with different environments display in two columns in the same row.

Comment: Do you want to display two column in single `<td>` or you want to display some environment variable inside view ?

Comment: I just want to display the value of row 1 in the first td and the value of row 2 in the second td

Comment: The best approach would be processing the data from Java side to be in the form you want/need probably using a `List<DataYouWantToAssociate>` and then using nested `<c:forEach>`.

Comment: that is what I have now, my quest is how to process the data in the form i want.